# convert rgb image to binary image in R using EBImage package

Tags: r, image-processing

I need to convert rgb image into binary image so that I can use `bwlabel()` function to detect the no of objects in the image in R. I have just started working on image processing, so I don't have any idea how to do it. I am using `EBImage` package.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Use the channel function to convert the image to black and white, then use thresholding to convert that to a binary image. Then you can use bwlabel to identify the number of sets of connected pixels. Note that the result you get will be very dependent on the threshold you pick. See the vignettes: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.pdf

Comment: how to choose the optimal threshold value for an image??

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. I recommend experimenting with different thresholds until you get an answer that makes sense for the task at hand. Below is an example with the Lena image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example with the lenac image from the package:

```
lenac = readImage(system.file("images", "lena-color.png", package="EBImage"))
lena = channel(lenac, "gray")
lena5 = lena > 0.5
labels = bwlabel(lena5)
max(labels)
```

gives 770 objects in the lena picture. Since this is a picture of a face, dividing it into objects may not make much sense. Try different values of the threshold until you get something reasonable - it depends on the type of images you are working with.